# clang: error: unsupported option '-static-libgcc' on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, jogl, osx-mavericks

I am trying to compile jogl from source on my Mac Mini with Mac OSX mavericks, but getting
**clang: error: unsupported option '-static-libgcc' on Mac OSX Mavericks**
I have *XCode 5.0.1 (5A2053)* and installed the *Command line tools for OSX Mavericks*
Any hints on how to fix this issue

Comment: From the `gluegen/make` directory if you run `scripts/make.gluegen.all.macosx-clang.sh` it will build correctly using clang.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command called `gcc` is not really GCC on Mavericks.  It's just a copy of Clang:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

That means it doesn't support GCC-only flags like `-static-libgcc`.  Find out what part of your build system is generating that flag and get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks Carl. That seems to have fixed the compilation problem. Though i dont know how it will impact the output. ( I am a Java dev and completely new to C & GCC )

Comment: Where/How can I find this?

Comment: My error is the following:

    clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
    clang: error: no input files

Comment: @user5503 how can you find what?

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by putting this line in your gluegen.properties file (which should be in your Users/yourname directory):

```
gcc.compat.compiler=clang
```

This tells the JOGL build system that it's using Clang. Otherwise, it thinks it's using gcc, and tries to use gcc-specific options. This fails on Mavericks because gcc is now just a link to Clang.

Comment: This didn't help me, so I did as @Carl Norum advises and removed `-static-libgcc` from Makefiles