# Installing pyodbc fails on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: python, macos, pyodbc

When running `pip install pyodbc`, I get

```
In file included from .../build/pyodbc/src/buffer.cpp:12:
    .../build/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:52:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found
    #include <sql.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems that Mavericks has no sql.h under /usr/include

Did anyone manage to install pyodbc? Is there a known workaround?

Comment: As a relevant bit of information - unless something has changed between then and now, pypyodbc may have a problem with not reading the full column headers on 64-bit systems. I [fixed that here](https://github.com/waynew/pypyodbc)

Comment: Answered the question in following post for M1 Users:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693640/8291933

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As you noticed OSX Mavericks dropped sql headers that are required for PyODBC compilation.
Following these steps allowed me to install PyODBC:

1. Make sure you have iODBC library installed (http://www.iodbc.org/)
2. Download and extract iODBC sources
3. Run `pip install --no-install pyodbc`
4. `cd [VIRTUAL_ENV]/build/pyodbc`
5. Run `python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=[LIBIODBC_SOURCES]/include/`
6. Run `pip install --no-download pyodbc`:

   ```
   Installing collected packages: pyodbc
     Running setup.py install for pyodbc

       warning: no files found matching 'tests/*'
   Successfully installed pyodbc
   Cleaning up...
   ```

I could as well copy the files under `[libiodbc_sources]/include/` to my `/usr/include` and just run `pip install pyodbc`, but I didn't want to add files manually to system folders.

Comment: Well documented instructions for this process.  I ended up needing to use the ``-I`` flag for the include instead of ``--include-dirs`` for some reason.  But it worked!

Comment: Hey for someone new to the Mac environment, what do the folders [libiodbc_sources] and [VIRTUAL_ENV] refer to? I tried searching for them but couldn't find them...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: [LIBIODBC_SOURCES] is where you extract iODBC
[VIRTUAL_ENV] is python virtual env path (not special for Macs), if you are not using virtualenv, you will have the relevant directory in the python installation you use

Comment: With the latest version of pip, step 3 becomes `pip install --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc --no-install pyodbc==3.0.7`. Note that --no-install is deprecated.

Comment: do you know how to make pyodbc work with iodbc? I don't know how to configure "Driver" in odbcinst.ini.

Comment: With a recent version of pip, `--no-download` and `--no-install` are gone. I downloaded in a scratch directory using `pip install --download . pyodbc --no-binary pyodbc`, then untarred and cd-ed into the untarred directory; edited `setup.py` to have the right ODBC link library referenced ('iodbc' in my case), then Step 5. Finally, `pip install .` in place of Step 6 (with `--upgrade ` as necessary).

Comment: As @B98 mentioned, pip has removed `--no-download`. The easiest way I found was to grab the tarball directly from [github](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/releases)  and then continue on with the steps. Also, replace step #6 with `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Can anyone post an example of what [LIBIODBC_SOURCES] typically looks like? We have tried a variety of paths without success.

Comment: You can easily work around the missing --no-option by telling pip install where to find the includes, once you've installed iODBC.  `pip install  pyodbc --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/opt/local/include/"`

Answer (score 63):

You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install unixodbc, then pyodbc via pip in the usual fashion.

```
brew install unixodbc && pip install pyodbc
```

This works for me on Mavericks.

Comment: Upvoted at first, because it appeared to work. However it installed correctly, I couldn't get it to connect.

Comment: Does `pip` still work for `pyodbc`? I'm having the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054656/python-pip-unable-to-locate-pyodbc), and I'm surprised to see yours work.

Comment: `pip` does not work for `pyodbc`, but after unixodbc is installed building from source works.

Comment: if work if you use the link to the direct source (ex https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip). thanks for this as the original answer didn't work for me!

Comment: This went through for me with: sudp pip install pyodbc --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc

Comment: It will install, however you might notice issues such as this when running queries programmatically: `ProgrammingError: ('42622', '[42622] ERROR 3507:  Identifier "\xf2\xa0\x80\x8d\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xf2\xa0\x81\x94\x...`. Vitaly's answer correctly binds the include dirs to pyodbc for the build step

Comment: unixodbc does not work with pyodbc on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=356

Comment: This worked for me, but also had to install FreeTDS with `brew install freetds --with-unixodbc`. This was with Mavericks, Python 2.7.10, pyodbc 3.0.10.

Answer (score 31):

After many dead ends, this worked for me:

```
$ brew unlink unixodbc
$ brew install unixodbc  --universal
$ sudo pip install --upgrade --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/lib" --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc
```

Comment: This blog post was helpful in bringing this up to date for pyodbc-3.0.9 on OSX 10.9:  http://stefanoapostolico.com/2015/04/20/django_mssql_osx.html

Comment: Thanks! Macports works too by substituting 'usr' with 'opt'.

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer did not! Seems like it's more up-to-date.

Comment: For the second command, I am getting this `Error: invalid option: --universal`

Comment: Options `-allow-external` and `--allow-unverified` are gone. This answer isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score 14):

See my [installation instructions](https://gist.github.com/Bouke/10454272) which I've written after some futile attempts of the other answers provided:

First, install the following libraries:

```
$ brew install unixodbc
$ brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

FreeTDS should already work now, without configuration:

```
$ tsql -S [IP or hostname] -U [username] -P [password]
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> ^D
```

Onto unixODBC, we need to link to the driver, edit `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TD Driver (MSSQL)
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
FileUsage = 1
```

The test command we're using requires configuring a DSN, so edit `/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[MYDSN]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = [IP address]
Port = 1433
```

The configuration for your DNS might vary, you might need the `TDS_Version` or `Servername` directives. The above worked for me for SQL Server 2008 R2. Now, run the test command:

```
$ isql MYDSN [username] [password] -v
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> ^D
```

If the test succeeded, you can continue onto installing the Python library `pyodbc`. The current version of writing (3.0.7) doesn't link with unixODBC on OS X, so a change has to be made to `setup.py`. Download the source package and extract it somewhere. Find the following lines (146-147):

```
    elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
        # OS/X now ships with iODBC.
```

And change this line:

```
        settings['libraries'].append('iodbc')
```

into:

```
        settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
```

Then run the following command to install:

```
> python install .
```

Now pyodbc should work:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.connect('DSN=MYDSN;UID=[username];PWD=[password]')
```

You don't need to have your DSN configured in `odbc.ini`, so clear that file. You probably want to select a database on connect, so change your connect line to read:

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=[IP address];PORT=1433;DATABASE=[database];UID=[username];PWD=[password]')
```

Note that you could also link to the library file of FreeTDS instead of using `odbcinst.ini`, like this:

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so;SERVER=[IP address];PORT=1433;DATABASE=[database];UID=[username];PWD=[password]')
```

Comment: Upvoted for showing the FreeTDS installation step, which most other answers ignore. I didn't need to edit any of the files you mentioned, though. Just install unixodbc, freetds, and pyodbc. This may have been due to improvements in more recent versions of pyodbc (current is 3.0.10).

Comment: I'm getting `Error: invalid option: --with-unixodbc`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

I had no joy with @Vitaly's answer because there appears to be an issue building packages on Mavericks to do with the lack of support for hard-linking.  I couldn't get the package to build.

So I opted for @Vitaly's second suggestion which was to copy the necessary files from the `[libiodbc_sources]/include/` directory to `/usr/include` and the install worked find.  Here is a list of the files you will need to copy:

- sql.h
- sqltypes.h
- iodbcunix.h
- sqlext.h
- sqlucode.h

Comment: Where is /usr/include and where is [libiodbc_sources]? Libiodbc didn't indicate where it is installing when we unpackaged it.

Comment: @Praxiteles hope you found an answer by now, but if not for version 3.52 of iODBC you can find the [libiodbc_sources] at `/Library/Frameworks/iODBC.framework/Versions/3.52/Headers`.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me after trying just about everything else suggested.

```
brew install unixodbc
sudo pip install --upgrade --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/lib" --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc
```

Running Mac OS 10.11.1,Homebrew 0.9.5, and pip 7.1.2

Comment: allow-unverified threw a "no such option" error. Suggestions?

Comment: @Praxiteles Did you copy paste as is?

Comment: Works on Homebrew 1.3.4, pip 9.0.1, MacOS 10.12

Comment: Even simpler, this worked for me: `brew install unixodbc; pip install pyodbc`

Comment: It worked for me:
`brew install unixodbc;  pip3 install --upgrade --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include" --global-option="-L/usr/local/lib" pyodbc`

Answer (score 2):

If you see errors like

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
```

The problem is that with Mavericks Apple has removed **gcc** from the command line developer tools; it is now **clang** just *symlinked* to **gcc**. The `--mno-fused-madd` flag is not supported by clang (same goes for lots of other flags).

One solution might be to install gcc using homebrew or another method and symlink /usr/bin/gcc to a proper gcc.

A simpler workaround that worked for me is suppressing these error by turning them into warnings:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

After settings that I was able to `pip install pyodbc` without errors.

PS! In future versions of clang this might not be possible. At least it works on:

```
$> gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Refs:
https://bitbucket.org/cffi/cffi/issue/46/unused-mno-fused-madd-clang-warnings-on-os
https://coderwall.com/p/lqpp8w
[clang: error: unsupported option '-static-libgcc' on Mac OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649634/clang-error-unsupported-option-static-libgcc-on-mac-osx-mavericks)

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the whole process on Mac OS X; connecting to pyodbc to MS SQL Server 2014. The whole process is as follows:

Connection pipeline:

```
pyodbc ----> iodbc ----> freetds ----> MS SQL Server 2014
```

1. Build freetds (the SQL Server driver/connector):

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-tdsver=8.0

   make

   sudo make install

   // you should see /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so was generated

   //test method 1:

   TDSVER=8.0 tsql -H hostname -p 1433 -U username -P XXX -D databasename

   //test method 2:

   //config /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf
   [mssqlserver]
       host = XXX
       port = 1433
       tds version = 8.0

   //run

   tsql -S mssqlserver -U username -P XXX -D databasename  

   //if you can run sql, good to go!
   ```
2. Build iodbc (ODBC manager):

   ```
   //download from github, go to the folder

   cd mac

   ./configure 

   ./make

   sudo ./make install

   //config /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
   [mssqlserver]
   Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
   TDS_Version=8.0
   Server=xxxx
   Port = 1433
   Trace = Yes
   Description=XXX

   //test

   which iodbctest

   iodbctest 

   DSN=masqlserver;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx

   //if you can run sql, good to go!
   ```
3. Connect pyodbc (Python ODBC wrapper) to iodbc:

   ```
   pip install pyodbc 

   //in python,

   conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=mssqlserver;UID=xxx;PWD=xxxx")
   ```

Comment: If using Python, consider using a virtualenv. Toying with the system installed Python can create problems at the OS level. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I was successful with
sudo port install py-pyodbc

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my $0.02 to this.  Vitaly's answer was the main inspiration.

OSX 10.9.5, MacPorts 2.3.4, pip 8.1.2 (which did not have an --no-install option), virtualenv 14.0.6

Also helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942120/1394353

Anyway, install iODBC via **MacPorts**

`sudo port install libiodbc`

The missing sql.h is deposited by MacPorts @ **/opt/local/include**

Now, tell pip where it can find the includes (that's where the linked answer came in handy):

`pip install  pyodbc --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/opt/local/include/"`

Answer (score 0):

As `pip` doesn't support `--no-install` option anymore and the `--download` option is deprecated. I had to follow the following steps.

```
pip download pyodbc
tar -zxvf pyodbc-4.0.17.tar.gz
python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=[DIRECTORY CONTAINING THE HEADERS]
pip install pyodbc
```

Answer (score -1):

I met the the same problem today on ubuntu 14.04. I found some guy in below link said should install unixodbc-dev.

https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=55

I did it, and then the pip install success.

Hope this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

OS Version: El Capitan 10.11.6
Python Version: 2.7.11
Pip Version: pip 9.0.1

```
1. Install iodbc for Mac (my installation is in [iODB_loc]=/usr/local/iODBC)
2. pip install --download [download_location] pyodbc==3.0.10
3. cd [download_location]
4. tar -xvzf pyodbc-3.0.10.tar.gz
5. cd pyodbc-3.0.10
6. vim setup.py: 
settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
->
settings['libraries'].append('iodbc')
7. python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=[iODB_loc]/include/
8. pip install --upgrade .
```