# Install PYODBC on mac os x Mavericks

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

How does one install pyodbc in mac os x? I would like to connect remotely to a MySQL instance. I would like to install it so that I could use it from within terminal

(/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework)

I have spent the last 10 hours trying everything on stack overflow and the web with no luck. I still need to install pyv8 and rpy

Comment: There's a native MySQL driver is available for Python. Is there any reason you're not using MySQL-python? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5 (sudo pip install MySQL-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074620/installing-pyodbc-fails-on-osx-10-9-mavericks

Comment: @FlipperPA I have downloaded mysql-python and mysqldb they are located in the /usr/local.. folder rather than /System/library.. (where my python libs are) how do I import the lib in my program?

Comment: I get this error when trying to install pip


"error: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory"