# Installing pyodbc fails on OSX 12.2 (Monterey)

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyodbc

On macOS 12 `pip install pyodbc` results in error:

```
src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found
```

For older versions of macOS and Pip, this topic has been addressed in [Installing pyodbc fails on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20074620/1548275). None of the provided answers there are not working with current versions.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** Reasons for failure seem to vary a lot over time given version of macOS, Pip, Homebrew, and unixODBC.

Running `pip install pyodbc` while specifying the location of unixODBC library works in pyodbc 4.0.32:

```sh
CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/include' \
  LDFLAGS='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/lib' \
  pip install pyodbc
```

There seems not to be need to install iODBC as unixODBC works.

Additionally, getting ODBC Driver for SQL Server is as tangled. Documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos isn't accurate as OpenSSL version 3 and 1 fails to correctly detect at install time.

Because of OpenSSL version conflict, connection attempts to SQL server will result in errors like:

- SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed].
- Client unable to establish the connection.
- WARNING: <command/library here> is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way (followed by a process crash)

Various attempts to fix driver loading are described in https://github.com/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/59.

Manually symlinking OpenSSL 1.1 fixes the problem at the time of writing:

```sh
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Please understand, this is subject to change.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Please, provide any details on how your install fails.